# Load image disregarding of route depth level

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I want to load a logo image in my header. The `header.blade.php` template is `@include`-ed in the master layout which wraps all other templates (typical structure).

Right now, in the header template, I'm doing this:

`<img class="logo" src="{{ $levels }}images/logo.png">`

whereas in each action that loads a view (template), I do this:

```
$url = explode('/', Request::url());
$levels = '';
for ($i = 1; $i != count($url) - 3; $i ++) {
    $levels .= '../';
}
...
return View::make('whatever.view')
        ->with('levels', $levels);
```

Ew... That's fugly! But it works.

Yet, I know (but could not find) that there is an elegant way of accessing the `/public/images/` dir from whatever the depth of the route. Because if I do it simply `<img src="../images/logo.png">` then it's gonna work for the `/account/myprofile` route, but it's not gonna work for `/account/{id}/edit`...

No, `public_path()` does not help me in this case.

So, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make it relative to the root by prepending the url with a forward slash.

```
<img class="logo" src="/images/logo.png">
```

A url that starts with a forward slash is root-relative so no matter where you are on the site, it will be root + '/images/logo.png'.

Comment: ARE YOU KIDDING ME?! Can I be so lame...?! :D
Anyway, I'll leave this post for future lame-os like me to learn smth. :)
Thanks.

Comment: Hahaha, no, not lame. Your method was...creative.